# Problem with simplifying summation

Tags: summation

I have $$-2[\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i*(\bar y)) - \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i*(\bar x)*\frac {S_{(xy)}}{S_{(xx)}})+\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i*x_i*\frac {S_{(xy)}}{S_{(xx)}})]$$

This is a term of a larger sum I am dealing with to derive something in regression. I am allowed to pull out the $y_i$'s in each term because they appear in each sum?

thank you.

Comment: MathJax hint:  to get multicharacter subscripts, enclose them in braces like the lower sum limit.  So S_{(xy)} gives $S_{(xy)}$

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. It was an inquiry myself.

Comment: That is general in MathJax and LaTeX.  Anything in braces is treated as a unit.  In a sense, the braces should be required, but the language allows you to remove them around a single character item, which makes $x^2$ much easier to type.

Answer (score 0):

In the first two terms you can distribute out the $\sum_{i=1}^ny_i$ because nothing else in the sum depends on $i$.  Really you are distributing out the other terms.  This does not work in the third term because of the $x_i$.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake posting the question. Please look at my last edit.

Comment: I don't see anything in the edit which changes my point.  Presumably the $S$s are sums over $xx$ or $xy$ but they could have a different dummy variable, say $j$